# How much slower is it to put .js in an external file rather than directly on the page?

Tags: html, pagespeed

I assume that if you put some Javascript code in an external source (and use the src="") that it's a little slower b/c the page has to then download another portion, but I'm wondering whether that's inconsequential.

From testing I've done online (with [webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org)) seems quite small (< 5% of the total page time loading).

But just wondering about what's happening "under the hood" and whether the browser (I assume) is spinning up another process to download that bit separately rather than coming across from the server with the rest of the page is actually just as fast (b/c it's happening in parallel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not slow enough to matter.

I think the speed difference question is a red herring. Generally, you should keep your script separate from your html:

- Separation of concerns: the html is the structure of the site, whereas the script is its behavior.  It [mixes concerns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/86595/28793) to mingle them together, and it's [best practice](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/best-practices-for-modern-javascript-development) to keep your script in a separate file.
- It might seem counter-intuitive that script served separately from html could be just as fast or [even faster](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/rule_8_make_jav/), but things like [caching proxy servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server), [content delivery networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), and even new web protocols like [SPDY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) can make the speed question completely moot.

Answer (score 1):

If you test in Firebug in Firefox you'll see that Firefox is downloading multiple files at the same time (the number of concurrent files is different for each browser). But the main reason why you should put js code in external files is that it can be minified and compressed on the server side, and also cached by the browsers. Loading it from an external file has also the benefits of being able to load it from a static domain (cookie less) and use a CDN to speed up the delivery. So to reply to your question it'll be slower to put it in the page as the browser will need to download it every time it loads the page.